# ng-bind-html not removing &amp;

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

So i've got a page that is displaying some twitter JSON and it's littered with `&` that display as `&amp;`

I've included ngSanitize in my app:
`var teenSite = angular.module("teen.myapp", ['ngRoute', 'slickCarousel', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages','mm.foundation'])`

and in my view i'm using ng-bind-html:
`<span ng-bind-html="items.text | linky:'blank_'" />`

when text is displayed links are properly formatted in `<a>` tags and function properly but the posts have `&amp;` through out them.

Example output:`Smile it's finally #Friday! Weekends R the perfect time 2 visit ur @PlaceIWork &amp; work on ur Short`

I've reviewed the angular documentation regarding ng-bind-html and think i'm doing this right.  What is going on here?

Comment: What's `items.text`and `linky`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a filter, like so...

```
var app = angular.module("teen.myapp", ['ngRoute','slickCarousel','ngSanitize','ngMessages','mm.foundation','ngResource']);

app.filter("cleanUp", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(textToCleanUp){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(textToCleanUp);
  }
}]);
```

Then use it as so:

```
<span ng-bind-html="items.text | linky:'blank_' | cleanUp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  For some reason trustAsHtml is not working and i'm still getting the `&amp;` in my output.  With that said i dropped a regex replace in this filter and it seems to do the trick.

I didn't know about filters so this will come in handy later as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ampersands to &amp, and it should display ampersands.